# Trouble implementing recursive method for mean of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I have an array of numbers(double) and I want to implement a recursive method in C# to calculate a running average for a given position in the array using the following algorithm:

µ<sub>n+1</sub> = (n * µ<sub>n</sub>)/(n+1) + X<sub>n+1</sub>/n

where µ<sub>n+1</sub> is the average at the position I'm interested in,
µ<sub>n</sub> is the average of the prior iteration and X<sub>n+1</sub> is the nth element of the array.

I have been able to do it with an averaging function and an iterative function but not recursion:

```
    static double Flow(double[] A, int n)
    {
        double U = (A[0] + A[1]) / 2.0;
        if (n == 2) { return U; }
        else if (n == 1) { return A[0]; }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
            {
                U = Avg(A, U, i);
            }
        }
        return U;
    }

    static double Avg(double[] A, double M, int n)
    {
        double a =(n - 1) * M / (n);
        double b = A[n - 1] / (n);
        return a + b;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: Usually one goes down instead of up with last check like `n==0` or `n==1` ... Resulting code will be easier to read for most...

Comment: That should probably be X_{n+1}/(n+1). Why are you using recursion here, though? It will do nothing for dealing with overflow, and will be far slower than the naive sum-up-and-divide-by-n approach.

Comment: @G.Bach - Speed isn't the problem - not by a long shot. It's the stack size that is the problem. I tried measuring with 10,000 doubles and the recursion took 0.9549 milliseconds. When trying with 20,000 doubles I blew the stack. Stack size is the problem. Not speed.

Comment: @Enigmativity - you have stack problems because you've used wrong language as C# does not optimize tail recursion - need one that does (F# should work)... Really this looks like potential candidate for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com "Shortest C# recursive code for mean of an array" and not very good SO question (i.e. missing question part) - so my suggestion of Y-combinator looked fine to me a that moment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I didn't use the wrong language - the question was about c# and this kind of recursive function easily just blows the stack.

Comment: @Enigmativity - sorry - forgot to add smiley face. I should have just vote to close and move on - done.

Comment: user3716957, please explain why you need recursive algorithm, why you need to count up in your recursion AND what "isn't quite what I need" means - so far it is hard to answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I was asked to use a recursive algorithm for this project but not sure how literally that was meant since my updated code is iterative but uses the averaging method recursively. My original code was not giving me the right outputs and that is what I meant by "not what I need". The reason I need to count up in my recursion (though I suppose I could reverse the array and count down?) is that my next step is to introduce an α parameter which will be used to weight more recent data, I wanted to get the averaging right first though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define µ1, whatever your initial value of the first average is, for your algorithm to work. Also, variable i is not involved in your expression so what's it? Since Xn+1 is divided by n, I presume it can't be zero. Then the function should look like this:

```
double Avg(double[] array, int n)  
{    
    if (n = 2) 
    {
    return u1/2+array[2]; //u1 is a set value.
    }  

    return (n-1)*Avg(array, n-1)/n+array[n]/(n-1);
}
```

Last but not least, it's more convenient to express recursive algorithm in µn = ... µ(n-1) instead of µ(n+1)=...µn.